# Changing an element in a 2D array changes the whole column

Tags: python, arrays

I am having trouble with what I believe to be the stupidiest thing ever.

I have a 2D boolean array `board` with a dimension of 16x16:

```
[[False, False, False, ..., False], 
[False, False, False, ..., False], 
[False, False, False, ..., False], 
..., 
[False, False, False, ..., False]]
```

I want to access a specific element of it `(r,c)` and invert it. I wrote this function:

```
def flip(self, r, c):
        #flips the tile in position (r, c)
        self.board[r][c] = not self.board[r][c]
```

The problem I'm encountering is that this changes the whole column.

So for example, `flip(0,0)` makes the whole first column to be `True`, instead of only the element at `(0,0)`

I have no idea why, could someone shine some light on this for me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you create it? If it's actually a nested list and not an array, this is probably a duplicate: [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](/q/240178/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks! That did the trick. (How should I mark this as a solved question?)

Comment: We don't exactly do "solved" on Stack Overflow. You would need an answer to be able to [accept](/help/accepted-answer) it, but I've already closed the question since it's a [duplicate](/help/duplicates). You've got your answer and if anyone visits here in the future they'll be pointed to the same, so there's no need to do anything more :)